# Is there a way to force a Win32 Timer to execute when not idle?

Tags: winforms, win32gui

Win32 Timers created with SetTimer normally only execute when the message queue is empty. Is there any way to manually force an execution in the case the GUI thread is very busy and thus not empty?

(Edit)
As discussed below, in particular this is about having low priority messages (in this case indirectly to show a tool tip) continue to work when saturating the UI thread (but not blocking it). Here's some code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ToolTipTesting
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      Thread _thread = null;
      bool _run = false;
      bool _exit = false;

      public Form1()
      {
         var tsbStart = new ToolStripButton();
         tsbStart.Text = "Start";
         tsbStart.Click += (s,e) => _run = true;

         var tsbStop  = new ToolStripButton();
         tsbStop.Text = "Stop";
         tsbStop.Click += (s,e) => _run = false;

         var tslValue = new ToolStripLabel();

         var ts = new ToolStrip();

         ts.Items.Add(tsbStart);
         ts.Items.Add(tsbStop);
         ts.Items.Add(tslValue);

         Controls.Add(ts);

         _thread = new Thread(() =>
         {
            int i = 0;

            while (!_exit)
            {
               if(_run)
               { 
                  var result = BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { tslValue.Text = (i++).ToString(); ts.Update(); } ));

                  while(!_exit && !result.IsCompleted)
                     result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10);
               }
               else
               {
                  Thread.Sleep(100);
               }
            }
         });

         FormClosing += (s,e) =>
         { 
            _exit = true;
            _thread.Join();
         };

         _thread.Start();
      }
   }
}
```

If this is "the wrong way to do it"...happy to hear the "right way to do it."

Comment: Use something other than SetTimer if you don't like how SetTimer works.

Comment: Hey Raymond!! In this case, we're a few levels removed...we set a tool tip on ToolStripButton, but found when our gui thread is busy the tooltips stop working. We tracked that to WM_MOUSEHOVER, which isn't being generated. Then we know that TrackMouseEvent is creating a timer underneath. So, we could roll our own tooltip logic everywhere, but that is undesirable.

Comment: If the GUI thread is busy, it also won't respond to input (because input messages are also low priority), so it has no way of knowing whether to dismiss or not, so forcing the timers to run won't help. (And if the UI thread is busy, it can't do any UI work anyway.) The solution is to stop hanging the UI thread.

Comment: We have a secondary thread which queues up things to do using EndInvoke(BeginInvoke(...)). So we don't lock the UI thread, but call that fast enough that the queue is never empty (or long enough to process low priority message). It still responds to mouse messages (e.g. the ts buttons change color when you enter), but the low priority messages get lost. If we throttle then things begin to work normally, but the throttle time is dependent on the work load, and seems non-ideal as it globally makes things slower. For WM_PAINT, we have UpdateWindow. But for WM_TIMER I don't know.

Comment: BTW I laughing to myself translating this into an The Old New Thing article "First the customer asked about this...but when asked really cared about that, and when we dug deeper, we got to the key detail." :)

Comment: I think you can `PeekMessage(…, (QS_TIMER)<<16)` to force timer messages to be generated. The background thread could periodically BeginInvoke a custom action to the UI thread to do the magic PeekMessage.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out that solution. Otherwise, do you have any suggestions to approach this general pattern in a better way?

Comment: The better way is to stop inundating the UI thread with work. Do as much as you can on the background thread and notify the UI thread when the work is done (and possibly even buffer up the notifications and flush them out, say, every 100ms).

Comment: Well - I'd love to discuss it more but I don't want to take up any more of your time. I really appreciate your knowledge and advice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! As Raymond Chen suggests above, the solution is to use PeekMessage. Here is the completed code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ToolTipTesting
{
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   public struct NativeMessage
   {
      public IntPtr handle;
      public uint msg;
      public IntPtr wParam;
      public IntPtr lParam;
      public uint time;
      public System.Drawing.Point p;
   }

   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      static extern bool PeekMessage(ref NativeMessage lpMsg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax, uint wRemoveMsg);

      const int QS_TIMER = 0x0010;
      const int WM_TIMER = 0x0113;

      Thread _thread = null;
      bool _run = false;
      bool _exit = false;

      public Form1()
      {
         var tsbStart = new ToolStripButton();
         tsbStart.Text = "Start";
         tsbStart.Click += (s,e) => _run = true;

         var tsbStop  = new ToolStripButton();
         tsbStop.Text = "Stop";
         tsbStop.Click += (s,e) => _run = false;

         var tslValue = new ToolStripLabel();

         var ts = new ToolStrip();

         ts.Items.Add(tsbStart);
         ts.Items.Add(tsbStop);
         ts.Items.Add(tslValue);

         Controls.Add(ts);

         _thread = new Thread(() =>
         {
            int i = 0;

            NativeMessage nativeMessage = new NativeMessage();

            while (!_exit)
            {
               if(_run)
               { 
                  var result = 
                        BeginInvoke
                        (
                           new Action
                           (
                              () => 
                              {
                                 tslValue.Text = (i++).ToString();

                                 PeekMessage
                                 (
                                    ref nativeMessage,
                                    IntPtr.Zero,
                                    WM_TIMER,
                                    WM_TIMER,
                                    QS_TIMER << 16
                                 );

                                 ts.Update();
                              } 
                           )
                        );

                  while(!_exit && !result.IsCompleted)
                     result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10);
               }
               else
               {
                  Thread.Sleep(100);
               }
            }
         });

         FormClosing += (s,e) =>
         { 
            _exit = true;
            _thread.Join();
         };

         _thread.Start();
      }
   }   
}
```